# Hide window "processing classes for simulated method breakpoints" . IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, remote-debugging

I see little window "processing classes for simulated method breakpoints"(*) after I installed the new version of IntelliJ IDEA (2017.1.3) and tried to start debugger (remote). It takes some time for this process finish and I will be able to click to IDEA and do smth with my EE_application.

How can I hide this?
How I can start my debugger faster?

*[it looks so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGhGw.jpg)

Comment: Try removing all method breakpoints in Run | View Breakpoints...

Comment: @yole i haven't got any breakpoints

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove all method breakpoints and disable async stacktraces (Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Async Stacktraces)

Comment: where can I find "async stacktraces" property?  i can't find this settings at all

Comment: Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Async Stacktraces

Comment: I haven't got any Async Stacktraces, but I problem is actual

Comment: are you sure you do not have any method breakpoints? Please check in the breakpoints dialog.

Comment: It wasn't any breakpoints. Problem solved after Idea has update